# Using laplace trasnform find the convulation of (f*g)(t).

Tags: laplace-transform

$let \;f(t)=\sin (3t)$ and $g(t)=e^{-2t}$

Using laplace trasnform find the convulation of (f*g)(t).

convulation theorem: $h(t)=(f*g)(t)= \int ^t_0 f(u) g(t-u) du$

$L(sin (3t)=\frac{3}{s^2+9}\\
L(e^{-2t})=\frac{1}{s+2}$

then how we processed for this problem

Comment: The Laplace transform of a convolution is the product of the two Laplace transforms. So do you know how to find both of those Laplace transforms individually?

Comment: @TylerHG....yes i added now then what next

Comment: Then multiply those two together and do an inverse Laplace transform

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(t)=(f*g)(t)$. We have
$$\mathcal{L}\{f*g\} = \mathcal{L}\{f\} \cdot \mathcal{L}\{g\}$$
that is
$$H(s)=F(s)G(s)= \frac{3}{s^2+9}\cdot\frac{1}{s+2} =-\frac{9}{13}\cdot\frac{s}{s^2+9}+\frac{6}{13}\cdot\frac{3}{s^2+9}+\frac{9}{13}\cdot\frac{1}{s+2} $$
and then
$$h(t)=\mathcal L^{-1}\{F(s)G(s)\}=\left[ -\frac{9}{13}\cos(3t)+\frac{6}{13}\sin(3t)+\frac{9}{13}\mathrm e^{-2t} \right]u(t)$$